# If folder already exists add next number to folder name

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for creating new folder on users desktop. I would like to add more functionality to it. Before creating new folder it should check if folder already exists (it is doing it right now). Then if there is folder with the same name, code should create new folder with next available number 1,2,3...

So if there is already folder with name "T34-23, Quotation", code should create folder named "T34-23, Quotation 1". If there is "T34-23, Quotation 1" then create "T34-23, Quotation 2" etc.

```
 Sub MakeMyFolder()

    Dim fdObj As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fdObj.FolderExists(Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK2").Value & ", " & _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK7").Value) Then
        'MsgBox "Found it.", vbInformation, "Excel"
    Else
        fdObj.CreateFolder (Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK2").Value & ", " & _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK7").Value)
        'MsgBox "It has been created.", vbInformation, "Excel"
    End If

    Set fdObj = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You should create a worksheet variable to make your code much, *much*, more readable since you can substitute your variable back into your action statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @urderboy suggests, you should use some variables in this.

```
Function CheckAndSuffixFolder(strPathToCheck As String, _
                                Optional blnCreateFolder As Boolean = False) As String

Dim f As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim l As Long
Dim s As String

s = strPathToCheck
l = 1

Do While f.FolderExists(s)
    l = l + 1
    s = strPathToCheck & l
Loop

If blnCreateFolder Then f.CreateFolder s

CheckAndSuffixFolder = s

End Function
```

Calling like so, I have Folder, FOlder1 and FOlder2.

`CheckAndSuffixFolder("C:\Workspace\Training\Folder")`  Gives me Folder3

Answer (score 1):

Can't test it out now, but I'm thinking the solution will require you to loop through numbers until there is one that value that returns False. If the file check returns True then the file exists increment up until you get to the number needed. untested code:

```
Dim  createFile Boolean: createFile = False
Dim i as Integer: i = 1

Do while createFile = False
Dim strDir As String
    strDir = folderDir & "T34-23, Quotation" & i & "\"
    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
         MkDir strDir
    createFile = True
    Else
     i = i+1
    End If

wend
```